# JSON to Python Dictionary

Tags: json, dictionary, python-3.x

http://www.pr2hub.com/files/server_status_2.txt

There is the JSON file. I want to split them up into each category("server_id", "server_name", etc.)

I have tried tons of things but I dont even know how close I'm getting.

I want to get it like this:

```
import json

posts = ["{'author':'John Smith', 'translator':'Jane Doe'}"]

authors = []
translators = []

for post in posts:
    double_quotes_post = post.replace("'", '"')
    json_data = json.loads(double_quotes_post)

    author = json_data.get('author', None)
    translator = json_data.get('translator', None)

    if author: authors.append(author)
    if translator: translators.append(translator)
```

Comment: Why would you get it like *that*? Why don't you just get it normally?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> with open('server_status_2.txt', 'rb') as fp:
...   j = json.load(fp)
...   print j['servers'][0]
... 
{u'status': u'open', u'server_id': u'1', u'server_name': u'Derron', u'tournament': u'0', u'happy_hour': u'0', u'address': u'198.74.57.185', u'guild_id': u'0', u'port': u'9160', u'population': u'130'}
```

Comment: Well, this doesn't work the way you are posting. the print command is missing brackets, and also -- I don't own the file -- It is a file on the internet. It says "no such file or directory". Couldn't you have at least test your code before you gave it to me?